# JavaScript: Augmenting the Object/Function prototype avoiding name conflicts

Tags: javascript, prototype, conflict

Good day to everybody,

is there a method to augment the javascript Object and Function elements avoinding conflict issues? Let me be more specific:

Suppose i have 2 .js files :

ex1.js    has  `Object.prototype.aMethod=function(){/*a function*/}`

ex2.js    has  `Object.prototype.aMethod=function(){/*another function*/}`

In this situation, the ex1.js augmentation is overwritten by the one on ex2.js .

My question :

Is there a way to limit the effects of an augmentation to his file context, or better, to a module context?

EDIT:

Actually, i am reading crockford' s book JavaScript: the good parts, where he uses the prototype augmentation of Object and Function as something normal to do, without talking about the conflict issue. that' s strange, since the book leans to not pollute the global namespace. So i thought there must be some sort of workaround.

Comment: You shouldn't be mutating the global `Object.prototype`.

Comment: David is right. How about you explain what you are trying to do with this, and we can suggest how you should be doing it differently.

Comment: I think Crockford gets around to explaining why mutating `Object` is wrong. You should use `aMethod(thisObj, args...)` instead of `thisObj.aMethod(args...)` at the very least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype modifications are global if the Object you're modifying is global. To support what you're trying to do, you could use a module-local prototype:

```
var MyObject = function(properties) {
  var key;
  for(key in properties) {
    if(properties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this[key] = properties[key];
    }
  }
};

MyObject.prototype.aMethod = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

var obj = new MyObject({name: "blah"});
obj.aMethod();

// Prints "blah"
```

Modifying `Object.prototype` is usually considered "evil" on javascript, since the inherited properties show up on every `for-in` loop afterwards. Please note that modifying `Object.prototype` is different from modifying the `Object` object, which is what libraries such as [Sugar.JS](http://sugarjs.com/) usually do.

Comment: I see. that seems a little troubling in respect to what' s worth. native augmentation is something i should use when i am sure i am working in a controlled environment . thank you for the response

Comment: The problem usually lies on `Object.prototype`, because of the `for..in` loop. Modifying `Array.prototype`, `String.prototype` and others usually isn't as troublesome. It is important to note that some libraries, such as jQuery, assume that you don't modify `Object.prototype`.